# problems setting up vnc on centos

Tags: centos, vnc

I am new to using linux and would like to setup vnc - it used to work but I don't know what has happened and now it doesn't seem to be working. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. thanks.

**EDIT**

I have added this to the '/etc/sysconfig/vncservers'

```
VNCSERVERS="1:admin"
VNCSERVERARGS[1]="-geometry 800x600"
```

and my /home/admin/.vnc/xstartup file looks like

```
 #!/bin/sh

# Uncomment the following two lines for normal desktop:
# unset SESSION_MANAGER
# exec /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc

[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup 
[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources 
xsetroot -solid grey
vncconfig -iconic & 
xterm -geometry 80x24+10+10 -ls -title "$VNCDESKTOP Desktop" & 
gnome-session &

/usr/sbin/ss5 -m -t &

env LC_CTYPE=zh_TW.utf8 WINEPREFIX="/home/admin/.wine" wine "C:\ \Program Files\\uTorrent\\uTorrent.exe" &
```

However when I try and connect I get

[image]

And the /home/admin/.vnc/inverses:1.log file looks like

```
Sat Sep 26 17:44:15 2009
 vncext:      VNC extension running!
 vncext:      Listening for VNC connections on port 5901
 vncext:      Listening for HTTP connections on port 5801
 vncext:      created VNC server for screen 0
error opening security policy file /usr/lib/xserver/SecurityPolicy
Could not init font path element /usr/share/X11/fonts/TTF/, removing from list!
Could not init font path element /usr/share/X11/fonts/OTF, removing from list!
Could not init font path element /usr/share/X11/fonts/CID/, removing from list!
Could not init font path element /usr/share/X11/fonts/100dpi/, removing from list!
Could not init font path element /usr/share/X11/fonts/75dpi/, removing from list!
sh: /home/admin/.vnc/xstartup: Permission denied
```

Answer (score 2):

You could alternatively setup VNC to run as part of the XVNC startup by enabling the vnc.so module in the X config as follows:

Edit your XF86conig file located here:

> /etc/X11/xorg.conf

Modify the Module section to enable VNC as follows:

> Section "Module"
>   ...
>   ...
>   Load "vnc"
>   End Section

You can then enable security by adding the following to the Screen Section

> Section "Screen"
>   ...
>   ...
>   Option "SecurityTypes" "VncAuth"
>   Option "UserPasswdVerifier" "VncAuth"
>   Option "PasswordFile" "/root/.vnc/passwd"
>   EndSection

Lastly log in as root using su and create your VNC passwords using the following command:

> vncpasswd

Restart X or the machine and this should give you VNC access to X-Windows.

[Source](http://www.realvnc.com/products/free/4.1/x0.html)

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed response. I Managed to kinda resolve my problem by deleting the xstartup file which I am sure I've done many times to try and fix it and add gnome-session to the end line of the default script. The only problem now is: 
http://i36.tinypic.com/2iuf9rn.jpg

Comment: Never encountered that problem before. I ended up using the above method since it works best in most of my environments.

Answer (score 1):

You need to run the */etc/init.d/vncserver restart* command as the root user, try:

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/vncserver restart
```

Comment: How can I configure a display to use for the vncserver?